# Prevent calling ajax on scroll when already called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a plugin that tells me if an element is visible in the viewport with `$('#element').visible()` (set to `true` when visible).

Now I want to create a function that I scroll down a page and load new content with ajax. I have this so far:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log($('#ele').visible());

    if ($('#ele').visible()) {
               //ajax call comes here
    }

};
```

As soon as I see the element my log shows true:

[image]

I don't have problems implementing the ajax-request now, but shouldn't I block this function to occur only once? How could I prevent that a new element that already has been loaded to load again (prevent using ajax again)?

I thought of using a boolean-variable, but my problem is that I don't know how to implement that because if I set a variable, how would the browser know it's value? Because on every move of my mousewheel it cant remember what that variable's value was?

EDIT:

I tried the code of Ismail and it never reaches the ajax call (alert won't show).

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var ajaxExecuted = false;
    var ele = $('#load_more').visible();
    console.log(ele);

    return function() {
        if (ajaxExecuted) return;

        if (ele) {
            alert("OK");
            var ajaxArray;
            ajaxArray = { page: 2 }
            ajaxLoadContent(ajaxArray, "load_more", "ajax_load");
            ajaxExecuted = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
window.onscroll = (function() {
    var ajaxExecuted = false;
    return function() {
        if(ajaxExecuted) return;

        if ($('#ele').visible()) {
               $.ajax({...}).success(function() {
                   //Your code here;
                   ajaxExecuted = true;
               });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try that now. My question about that is how does the browser know that the value of the variable ajaxExecuted? I mean what is the background process step by step exactly?

Comment: So I tried this but the code never gets past `if(ajaxExecuted) return;` because it's set to true afterwards?

Comment: The outer function is an `Immediately-invoked function expression` that will return a function (the event handler). The event handler will be executed inside the IIFE function scope where `ajaxExecuted` is available.

Comment: Wait ! how much '#ele' did you have in your page ?

Comment: Just one, I tried alert() to check if the function will get to the ajax call and it never reaches it. See my updated question.

Comment: You need to put `$('#ele').visible()` inside the inner function ! the outer function is just an isolated scope it will be executed once !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116850/discussion-between-ismail-rbouh-and-vaia).

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution: set a boolean to true when the element first becomes visible and set it to false when it stops being visible. Only fire the request if those states mismatch (i.e. if it's visible but the boolean is false - that means it's the first time you've seen the window. You'd then set the bool afterwards so it won't fire off anymore until it disappears and reappears again).

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to implement that because if I set a variable, how would the browser know it's value because on every move of my mousewheel it cant remember what that variable's value is?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Unless I'm going crazy you should be able to create one above your function declaration and set it to false, and then modify it in the function..

Comment: I have updated my question using the code of Ismail. Maybe you can help me out too?